# How i can move element of dynamic vector in argument of function push_back for dynamic vector

Tags: c++, stdvector

how i can move element of dynamic vector in argument of function push_back for dynamic vector. Probably, i’ve said something and it isn’t right. Sorry, but i don't know English so good…

```
vector<int> *ans = new vector<int>();
vector<int> *x = new vector<int>();
ans->push_back(x[i]);
```

Comment: C++ and C# are very distinct programming language. What are you asking about?

Comment: A dynamic allocation of a `std::vector` is always a sign that you are doing something wrong

Answer (score 1):

`x` is a pointer to a single `vector`. You need to deference the `x` pointer before you can apply `operator[]` to that `vector`, eg:

```
vector<int> *ans = new vector<int>();
vector<int> *x = new vector<int>();
// put some elements in *x, then...
ans->push_back((*x)[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest

```
ans->push_back(x->at(i));
```

But I don't understand why you call that "move element."

BTW `vector<int>*` is nonsense. `x` manages a dynamically allocated memory and `vector<int>*` never looks good.

Comment: I just make the code faster and transfer it to the dynamic view as much as possible

Comment: `vector<int>*` does not make it faster and `vector<int>` can't be a bottleneck.